# HTTP 500 error - Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, bitnami

I got the above error while using bitnami django. 
All settings done according doc: 
https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/django/#production
python version: Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
django version: 2.0.2-3

wsgi.py:

```python
import os,sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject')
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE", "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/egg_cache")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyProject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

httpd-app.conf:

```conf
<IfDefine !IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED> 
Define IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-djangostack   processes=2 threads=15    display-name=%{GROUP}
</IfDefine> 

<Directory "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/MyProject">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-djangostack

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Require all granted

</Directory>

Alias /MyProject/static "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/static"
WSGIScriptAlias /MyProject '/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/MyProject/wsgi.py'
```

httpd-prefix.conf:

```conf
# Include file
Include "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

corresponding url added to /Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file

But when I'm trying to access app via browser I've got error in log:

```log
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.873873 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098] mod_wsgi (pid=29099): Target WSGI script '/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/MyProject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.874027 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098] mod_wsgi (pid=29099): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/MyProject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875482 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875554 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/MyProject/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875568 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875584 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875594 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875608 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875618 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875631 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875641 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875654 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875664 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]     module = import_module(entry)
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875677 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875687 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875700 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875728 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875736 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Jun 22 16:37:20.875752 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 29099] [remote ::1:62098] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'
```

I have installed widget_tweaks using:

```
pip3 install django-widget-tweaks
```

But when I stop Apache and run app using command

```shell
python3 manage.py runserver localhost:8080
```

the app works perfectly fine.

My urls.py under /Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/django_projects/MyProject/MyProject look like:

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include,re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('APP.urls')),
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
]
```

So I assume error within Apache configuration. Any help or advises will be appreciated!

Comment: How did you install a version of mod_wsgi which was compiled for Anaconda Python? The system package for mod_wsgi cannot be used with Anaconda Python as mod_wsgi needs to be compiled with the specific Python installation/version you want to use.

Comment: which url, you call when you see this error message?

Comment: Can I see your urls.py

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, I am editing the question to attach my urls.py

Comment: URL I call is localhost:8080/MyProject

Comment: I think when you run your prog with command, you use virtualenv. But when run it via apache, that does not use virtualenv and then cannot use python modules. Are you familiar with supervisor?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, No I am not

Comment: Hi Graham, Can you please share steps to install mod_wsgi on Ubuntu? When I try to install mod_wsgi on Ubuntu using pip3 install mod_wsgi, I get following error: File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9fuzlq70/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 168, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
    RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. mod_wsgi is enabled by default in our installations, you can check it by running `apachectl -M`. You will see that `wsgi_module` is in the list. Please note that you need to use the [Bitnami Console](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/bnconsole/) to run all the commands, for OS X, please execute `/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/use_djangostack`. This section of our documentation explains how to deploy a custom project https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/django/#how-to-create-a-new-django-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jota for providing one of the solution.

Solution 1: 
For Mac OS, when I execute /Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/use_djangostack, I enter Bitnami console.
I just had to install all the necessary modules and custom project ran successfully using apache.

Solution 2:
In case you don't wanna use bitnami console,

1) Install mod_wsgi using pip, preferably into a Python virtual environment. Ensure pip is for the version of Python you want to use.

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

2) Display the config to add to Apache configuration file to load this mod_wsgi by running:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

3) Take the output of above command to display config and add to Apache configuration. (httpd.conf file)

4) restart the apache using ctlscript.sh file. In my case the command looked like:

```
/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

5) After restarting, my custom project ran successfully.

Regards,

Amey Kelekar